# how to pass a variable to a component from history.replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

how can I access this match.chatroomId in the functional component ??
I use history.replace to redirect to the component
`` onClick = {() => history.replace(`/chat/${match.chatroomId}`)} ``

Answer (score 0):

using react hook `useParams()` This is url - http://localhost:8000/personal/1.

So in this case, `use const { id } = useParams()`

now, if you do console.log(id) , it will give you the exact id of the url. In this case it will give you 1.

useParams() extracts the id from the url and lets us use it.

Thanks.

Comment: did you import that hook from react library